# is there a programming / math term for what the linear() function does in After Effects?

Tags: javascript, math, easing, linear-interpolation, easing-functions

Adobe After Effects (an animation / compositing app) has a scripting language (Expressions) that's based on JavaScript, and it comes with a bunch of After Effects-specific functions built on top of JS. The function `linear()` is one of these. It considers the animated change in one object's property (say, the X position of a slider) and links that to another property (say, the rotation of some other object in the scene), so that the first animated property controls / animates the second property.

If that explanation is confusing, see 11:33 in this vid:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gK1Ejt7qND0&t=693s

The `linear()` function call looks like this:

```
linear(ref, refStart, refEnd, outStart, outEnd);
```

I don't know what the actual internal arg names are, but this is what they do:

`ref` == the "controller" property (in my earlier example, the X position of an object). Usually animated, varies over time.

`refStart` / `refEnd` == the lower and upper bounds of the ref property

`outStart` / `outEnd` == the lower and upper bounds of the destination property (in my earlier example, the rotation of another object)

Is there generic programming term for what this function does? Or a math term? As far as I can tell, it's something involving "interpolation," maybe linear interpolation, but I'm unclear.

Are there general programming / math libraries that include the equivalent of this function? After Effects also has eased versions of `linear()`, called `ease()`, `easeIn()`, and `easeOut()`. As far as I can tell, those might be called "easing functions" in programming, but not sure.

Bonus: I tried my hand at reverse-engineering AE's linear() from scratch. Pretty barebones and doesn't do any type checking or errors, but otherwise it seems to work identically in my testing in AE:

```js
function fauxLinear( ref, refStart, refEnd, outStart, outEnd ) {
    // constrain refTemp to range of refStart to refEnd
    let refTemp = 0;
    const refMin = Math.min( refStart, refEnd );
    const refMax = Math.max( refStart, refEnd );

    refTemp =   (ref < refMin) ? refMin :
                (ref > refMax) ? refMax : ref;

    // calculate input range and ref proportion
    const refRange = Math.abs( refStart - refEnd ) || .001; // avoid dbz
    const refRangeTarget = Math.abs( refMin - refTemp );
    const refProportion = refRangeTarget / refRange;

    // calculations for final output
    let outRange = [], outSlope = [], finalVal = [];
    const loopLen = ( Array.isArray( outStart ) ) ? outStart.length : 1;
    if (loopLen == 1) { outStart = [outStart], outEnd = [outEnd]; }

    for (let i = 0; i < loopLen; i++) {
        outRange[i] = Math.abs( outStart[i] - outEnd[i] );
        outSlope[i] = ( outStart[i] <= outEnd[i] ) ? 1 : -1;
        finalVal[i] = ( outSlope[i] * (outRange[i] * refProportion) + outStart[i] );
    }

    return ( loopLen == 1 ) ? finalVal[0] : finalVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a function which does [Linear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) some languages have a `lerp()` function or equivilent. But there does no seem to be anything in the javascript Math class.

Comment: I posted something I hope you can use! its in python but if you know java this well I bet you can figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a straight line among many other things very simply put lol. A square is 4x linear I guess you could say that. In a tool used with sound (EQ) it's linear from 0hz to 20k. What you are doing sounds very hard. If a and b are lines, they meet at your painted ball. The ball can move left, right, up and those you have in your function. This got me thinking hard. What's left? The mathematical term is *linear* also so you are right. I think

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-linear-programming-in-pulp/

I stumbled on this!

Sorry I do not know how to make this look better btw.